# What is completionHandler at performActionFor shortcutItem for?

Tags: ios, 3dtouch

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
```

I'm doing the UIApplicationShortcutIcon functionality in my app. I'm clearly understand that i should сall the completionHandler after shortcutItem was handled.
But how the calling of completionHandler with true or false reflects on the app?